# Why is this program giving me an array index out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

```
static char characters[] = { 'a', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'e', 'f', ' ' };

public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;

        if (characters[i] == ' ') {
            while (j < characters.length && characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000') {
                j++;  // increment j till a non-space char is found
            }
        }
    }

    for (char character : characters) {
        System.out.print(character + " ");
    }
}
```

Eclipse shows the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at loopchecker.main(loopchecker.java:13)

Line 13 is the `while loop`. But I am already checking if `j's` value is less than the length or not.

Comment: Should be dup of operator priority in java questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It´s because of the `or` operator.

The following condition reads like that

```
(j < characters.length && characters[j] == ' ') || characters[j] == '\u0000'
```

so you allways execute the or condition due to the precedence of the `and` operator above the `or` operator which causes the `ArrayOutOfBoundException.` You might want to include braces in your while condition.

```
while (j < characters.length && (characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000'))
```

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add some parentheses to your `while` statement:

```
while (j<characters.length && (characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000'))
```

Otherwise, Java's [order of operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) sees it as

```
while ((j<characters.length && characters[j] == ' ') || characters[j] == '\u0000')
```

which means `characters[j]` will still be evaluated if the first portion is false.

Answer (score 2):

Given that in the comment, you want to say `//increment j till a non-space char is found`, I would say that you should get rid of:

```
while (j<characters.length && characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000')
```

Which is causing your error due to the problem with the `||` being evaluated after the `&&` and replace it with:

```
while (j<characters.length && Character.isWhitespace(characters[j]))
```

This solves your problem along with dealing with the whitespace issue much more conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

The `characters[j] == '\u0000'` part doesn't have a check to ensure that j is less than the length. Put something like `j < characters.length && (.. || ..)`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the OR operator .
Below is the complete solution .

```
package com.java;

public class ArraySample 
{
    static char characters[]={'a','b',' ','c',' ','e','f',' '};
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            int j = i + 1;
            if (characters[i] == ' ') {
                while (j < characters.length && (characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000')) {

                    j++;  //increment j till a non-space char is found

                }

            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< characters.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(characters[i]+" ");
        }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static char characters[] = { 'a', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'e', 'f', 's' };

public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        int j = i - 1 ; // The problem was here J was surpassing the characters length

        if (characters[i] == ' ') {
            while (j < characters.length && characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000') {
                j++;  // increment j till a non-space char is found
            }
        }
    }

    for (char character : characters) {
        System.out.print(character + " ");
    }
}
```